# Nested dictionary comprehension extracting one key value pair

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a single key value pair using dictionary comprehension as an exercise, I have accomplished this using for loops but the best I can do using dictionary comprehension returns an entire dictionary. If I use anything other than 'inner_key01' or 'inner_key02' in the if portion of the below code I get an empty dictionary.

I would like the code to return 'inner_value22'

```
my_dict = {'inner_key01' :{'inner_key1': 'inner_value1', 'inner_key2': 'inner_value2'},
           'inner_key02' :{'inner_key21': 'inner_value21', 'inner_key22': 'inner_value22'}
}

next_dict = {inner_key: inner_value for inner_key, inner_value in my_dict.items() for outer_key, outer_value in my_dict.items()if inner_key == 'inner_key02'}

print(next_dict)
```

Comment: add expected output in your question

Comment: {'inner_key22': 'inner_value22'}

Comment: why you want only one key-value pair from given dict? please elaborate the logic

Comment: It's a learning exercise, can it be done or should I just stick to using for loops